# Error deploying Google's App Engine flex [nginx example]

Tags: nginx, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I am trying to [deploy Google's nginx hello world example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart#deploying_hello_world_to) via App Engine's flexible env. I'm using the same setup as detailed in the quick start guide, with the exception of network settings added to `app.yaml` (file contents below):

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
network:
  name: my_network
  subnetwork_name: my_subnet
```

For replication, my exact process is (from within a GCP cloud shell):

1. clone [Google's example repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-custom-runtimes-samples),
2. `cd` into the nginx directory,
3. update `app.yaml` to reflect the correct network setup (see above),
4. run `gcloud app deploy .` or `gcloud beta app deploy .`.

The result is an error 13:

```
53db376e88c7: Layer already exists
3baebd9b50ad: Layer already exists
1401df2b50d5: Layer already exists
57a9a0cdd450: Layer already exists
latest: digest: sha256:96324cd5dd0571fa98e461ecfc844cefc74c1bad7d621273f11f94e7676cde86 size: 2605
DONE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.                                                                                                       
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred.
```

I have attempted deploying with different healthcheck options but recieve the following:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Legacy health checks are no longer supported for the App Engine Flexible environment. Please remove the 'health_check' section from your app.yaml and configure updated health checks. For instructions on migrating to split health checks see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/migrating-to-split-health-checks
```

I assume the advice to do so is out of date.

The app itself runs fine from a docker container. Any advice would be welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google support supplied a solution which worked for me. However, Error 13 is relatively general so YMMV. In your deployment environment, run the following:

1. `gcloud config set interactive/hidden true`
2. `gcloud app update --service-account=PROJECT_DEFAULT_APP_ENGINE_SA`
3. `gcloud app deploy`

1 [exposes hidden commands/flags](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set) and 2 sets the active service account for the app.

**Beware -** a project's default App Engine SA is heavily permissioned so it may be worth isolating App Engine to its own project to minimise risk.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried reproducing the same scenario you have mentioned but no error was thrown to me. When adding the network to your app.yaml you have to make sure you use the short name for network, this is mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#network_settings).

The network settings in your app.yaml should look something like this:

```
network:
  instance_tag: TAG_NAME
  name: NETWORK_NAME
  subnetwork_name: SUBNETWORK_NAME
  session_affinity: true
  forwarded_ports:
    - PORT
    - HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT
    - PORT/tcp
    - HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT/udp
```

Where for `name` :

> Every VM instance in the flexible environment is assigned to a Google
> Compute Engine network when it is created. Use this setting to specify
> a network name. Give the short name, not the resource path (for
> example, default rather than
> https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project/global/networks/default).
> If you do not specify a network name, instances are assigned to the
> project's default network (which has the name default). If you want to
> specify a subnetwork name, you must specify a network name.

And for `subnetwork_name`:

> Optional. You can segment your network and use a custom subnetwork.
> Ensure that the network name is specified. Give the short name, not
> the resource path (for example, default rather than
> https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project/global/networks/default/subnetworks/default).The
> subnetwork must be in the same region as the application.

If you are using a VPC shared network for your project, this will help you do it, all you need to do is follow the step by step given [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-shared-vpc).

Comment: Thanks Froilan. This wasn't sufficient to solve my issue, unfortunately. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71734847/18364818) for the fix that worked for me